# How to obtain response curve characteristics (rise time, settling time, steady state, overshoot) for a non-linear system, from Simulink onto Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I obtain a response curve for my non-linear controller design on Simulink, and I am only able to obtain just the rise time and overshoot using 'Bilevel measurements' on the response curve tab in Simulink. Thus, I import this curve onto MATLAB using the following command in Command window:

*plot(simout.Time,simout.Data)*

After using the above code, I did obtain the same response curve in MATLAB as obtained in Simulink. But when I right click on the Figure in order to look for 'Characteristics-->Rise Time, settling time etc', this feature seems disabled i.e., I try to right click and nothing appears after I have imported the curve in MATLAB from Simulink.

Unlike when we have a transfer function (tf) defined in the command window, and then we type 'step' to obtain the response curve. Thus, on this figure when we right click, we can select characteristics--> rise time and other parameters.

I would be grateful if I can be assisted on how to obtain the system characteristics from a non-linear system's response curve.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data that is shown in the figure generated with the "[step](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.step.html;jsessionid=568730ab3ca536a89bca28aea2be)" command comes from the "[stepinfo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.stepinfo.html)" command.

For this case, you can use the stepinfo command with the time and output vector. [See Mathworks example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.stepinfo.html#mw_cab22a5a-b8ef-49fd-b071-3e7888430c00). The command will be like:

```
stepinfo(simout.Time,simout.Data,STEADYSTATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the above comment and link.

Comment: The following code line worked for me: stepinfo(simout.Data,simout.Time,'SettlingTimeThreshold',0.02)

Comment: I am trying to obtain the steady state error as well, I would be grateful if you can guide on steady state error as well. The following code for steady state error or something similar does not work: stepinfo(simout.Data,simout.Time,'SteadyStateError'). Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear it works for you. To get the Steady State Error, do you have the real end value? If is the case, I will do:
Error = simout.Data(end) - EndRealValue

Comment: Hi, I am still trying to figure out my non-linear controller design results. I am trying to obtain "transition time when the error reaches 1%." How can I obtain the above using stepinfo?